# Alternatives for mysql data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an alternative way to do this:

```
$resulter=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mail WHERE status='UNREAD'");
$a=0;
$name=$selfinfo["username"];
while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($resulter)){
Foreach($result as $aaa){
if($aaa["msgto"]==$name){
$a=$a+1;
}}}
echo("<br>$a Unread messages");
```

I keep ending up with this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'msgto' in /home/u534673521/public_html/test/loginsystem/members.area.php on line 18
```

And i have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: `Foreach` ---> `foreach`

Comment: Please, for your own sake, don't use `mysql_query` unless you absolutely have to. It's dangerous, deprecated, and will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: For low-level database work, [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is the best bet. You really should be using a [popular PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/), though. Doing queries by hand is a technique that largely went out of style in the 1990s because working at this level is incredibly time-consuming.

Comment: I am running on a server in which i do not have access to install framework i think.

Comment: A framework is just some `.php` files, so if you can upload code, you can use a framework. WordPress is an example of a framework, and I've never heard of a hosting company that would deny you that.

Comment: This is strange... I changed the version of php im running on to 5.3 and no error came up.